# Can't create table `mailorder`.`o_details` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

I have already made the parts table and set primary key as P_NO.

```
CREATE table o_details (
    O_NO int NOT null AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    P_NO int,
    QUANTIITY int,
    CONSTRAINT FK_PersonOrder 
    FOREIGN KEY (P_NO) REFERENCES parts(P_NO)

);
```

parts table

```
Create Table parts( P_NO int not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key, P_NAME varchar(255), QOH varchar(255), Price int, OLevel varchar(255) );
```

Comment: Please share the `create table` statement for table `parts`.

Comment: Create Table parts(
 P_NO int not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    P_NAME varchar(255),
    QOH varchar(255),
    Price int,
    OLevel varchar(255)
   
);

Comment: t1f i have to make foreign key from the parts table.

Comment: @AbdulWahab Check my answer.

Comment: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=dbf132ead1b76bac7b179789e2a275f0

Comment: @stickybit Me too. Weird, he says it isn't.

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: @AbdulWahab Glad to hear it. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE SCHEMA `mailorder` ;

    CREATE TABLE `mailorder`.`parts` (
      `P_NO` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `P_NAME` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
      `QOH` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
      `Price` INT NULL,
      `OLevel` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`P_NO`));

    CREATE TABLE `mailorder`.`o_details` (
      `O_NO` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `P_NO` INT NULL,
      `QUANTITY` INT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`O_NO`));


    ALTER TABLE `mailorder`.`o_details` 
    ADD INDEX `FK_PersonOrder_idx` (`P_NO` ASC) VISIBLE;
    ;
    ALTER TABLE `mailorder`.`o_details` 
    ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_PersonOrder`
      FOREIGN KEY (`P_NO`)
      REFERENCES `mailorder`.`parts` (`P_NO`)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: i am using mysql on xampp and this give syntax error.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2

Comment: How is it 'not working' ? I've created it on my mysql server right now using the exact code and it works fine. Explain what the problem is.

Comment: Be careful with visible indexes they are relatively new (v8.0 plus)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE table o_details ( O_NO int NOT null  PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1), 


P_NO int, QUANTIITY int, CONSTRAINT FK_PersonOrder FOREIGN KEY (P_No) REFERENCES parts(P_No)

);
```